# Moving Position of View animated

Tags: c#, ios, animation, uiview, xamarin.ios

I have a Problem with animating a movement of a View.
It works but it stucks if I start animating the movement. Without an animation it works fluently. But if I set the animation it starts stucking. Here is my code:

```
UIView.BeginAnimations("Slide");
this.detailController.View.Layer.Position = new PointF(50,50);
UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

I already tried:

- **Setting** :

> this.detailController.View.Center = new PointF(50,50);

- **Working with CoreAnimations**

Is there any possibility to make  thie animation more fluently ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks a performance problem. Does your app constantly logging or running some script in main threads?

Comment: No  the app just has to move the View at this moment. The View also doesn't resizes itself (LayoutSubviews etc). Just moving the Position of the View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default animation duration is .2 seconds, which might be too fast to be visible in your case.

If you want fluid animations, play with the duration and the easing functions. Just make sure you set those parameters at the beginning of the animation block (just after `BeginAnimation`) or they won't be taken into account.

```
UIView.BeginAnimations("Slide");

UIView.SetAnimationDuration (2);
UIView.SetAnimationCurve (UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseInOut);

detailController.View.Layer.Position = new PointF(50,50);
UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

For more info, read http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/animation/coreanimation/animate_a_uiview_using_uikit

Comment: First thanks for the response. I already tried setting the Duration to longer Durations. Then its getting more fluid. But this is to slow and also stucking a little bit. Also I tried playing with the Animation Curves but that changes nothing.

Comment: your view is then probably too heavy to animate, probably using shadows or transparency which are expensive to compute. I had that once, and solved by replacing the view shadow by an image (the cost of computing a shadow is proportional to it's surface, not it's perimeter)

Comment: Tanks for your Post Stephane. I disabled the Shadows. Now it works fluid. Thank you very mutch.

Comment: ha ! Shadows striking back ! Great I was helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to perform my animations like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:durationTime //in seconds
                     animations:^{
                         //what I want to animate (setCenter:, setFrame:,...)
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         //only if you want to do things after the animation
                     }
];
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: First thanks for the response. I already tried this and it changes nothing. Maybe its because i have an ipad 3 with retina. On my iPad 2 and iPad 4 it works very well. Only my iPad 3 makes problems.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard with autolayout?

Comment: No I override the Method "DidLayoutSubviews" to resize the Subviews. But the Method isn't executed at this moment. I think it has something to do with the retina display. Is there a possibility to make it more performant? Remove shadows?..?